# Debug problem with Ghidra 3rd party language

Tags: ghidra, java

I want to reverse engineer some 65816 code using Ghidra. Unfortunately the third-party 65816 language is broken. No problem, I can fix it myself. However, looking at the Ghidra error gives me no clue as to what the problem is. I've looked at the `.slaspec` and it appears to be correct so a verbose error would be helpful. The message mentions checking the log messages but I can't find anything.

Is there a way to debug the problem with the language?

Ghidra Error:

```
Errors compiling /home/rob/tools/ghidra_10.2.3_PUBLIC/Ghidra/Processors/65816/data/languages/65816.slaspec -- please check log messages for details
ghidra.app.plugin.processors.sleigh.SleighException: Errors compiling /home/rob/tools/ghidra_10.2.3_PUBLIC/Ghidra/Processors/65816/data/languages/65816.slaspec -- please check log messages for details
    at ghidra.app.plugin.processors.sleigh.SleighLanguage.reloadLanguage(SleighLanguage.java:520)
    at ghidra.app.plugin.processors.sleigh.SleighLanguage.initialize(SleighLanguage.java:150)
    at ghidra.app.plugin.processors.sleigh.SleighLanguage.<init>(SleighLanguage.java:116)
    at ghidra.app.plugin.processors.sleigh.SleighLanguageProvider.getNewSleigh(SleighLanguageProvider.java:112)
    at ghidra.app.plugin.processors.sleigh.SleighLanguageProvider.getLanguage(SleighLanguageProvider.java:99)
    at ghidra.program.util.DefaultLanguageService$LanguageInfo.lambda$getLanguage$0(DefaultLanguageService.java:385)
    at ghidra.util.task.TaskBuilder$TaskBuilderTask.run(TaskBuilder.java:306)
    at ghidra.util.task.Task.monitoredRun(Task.java:134)
    at ghidra.util.task.TaskRunner.lambda$startTaskThread$0(TaskRunner.java:106)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

[65816 language support](https://github.com/achan1989/ghidra-65816)

[Example binary](http://www.zimmers.net/anonftp/pub/cbm/firmware/misc/cmd/scpu-dos-1.4.bin)

Comment: Could you please check if you have application.log file in /home/rob/.ghidra/ directory or in any subdirectories?

Comment: @malikcjm I hadn't thought to check there. Unfortunately that directory is empty though.

Comment: Please try to look for application.log file in /home/rob/tools/ghidra_10.2.3_PUBLIC/ directory or any subdirectories

Comment: @malikcjm There are no logs

Comment: Can you share that third-party language and binary file that you tried to analyze?

Comment: Added links to the question. Thanks

Comment: I see that there were some problems with released versions up to 1.02. With latest changes I had no problem loading you example binary. https://github.com/achan1989/ghidra-65816/commit/6df2b00cf27af4bc3c259cf499ca2ea9b6f92522

Comment: @malikcjm Well that's a facepalm moment. I assumed the release version was the one to use - I never though to just take the current master! Thank you. If you want to make this the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that there were some problems with released versions up to 1.02. With latest changes I had no problem loading your example binary.
https://github.com/achan1989/ghidra-65816/commit/6df2b00cf27af4bc3c259cf499ca2ea9b6f92522